# Callback not working as expected in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, callback

I have a case where a user can request an invitation, but only if they don't have a request already in the system.  If they request an invitation, the `invitation.sender_id` is set to `"0"`, and if they received an invitation from a user, the `invitation.sender_id` is set to `current_user.id`, which will always be `>0`.

The `invitation.rb` model has `before_create :recipient_has_requested` and the callback is:

```
def recipient_has_requested
  if Invitation.exists?(recipient_email: :recipient_email, sender_id: 0)
    errors.add :recipient_email, 'An invitation has already been sent to that email address.'
  end
end
```

When I check the SQL in the log, I see:

```
Invitation Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."recipient_email" = 'recipient_email' AND "invitations"."sender_id" = 0 LIMIT 1
```

which I understand should be returning `'true'` to the callback, preventing the new invitation from being saved.  However, a glance at the database shows that I have multiple requests for an invitation, all from the same email address, and all with a `invitation.sender_id = 0`.

I'm new to this, so any help would be appreciated.  Why is the callback returning an unexpected result?

==EDIT==

I think the logic is reversed here.  The callback is finding a record matching the criteria, and therefore is returning `true`.

Can anyone take a look at the logic and tell me how to write it so it returns `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a bit more google-fu, I came across a couple of similar cases here in SOF.

Basically, I had the logic all wrong.  It was constructed as a callback but the logic was true.  I changed it to a validation with scope and it worked.

Here is the final snipit:

```
validates :recipient_email, uniqueness: { scope: :sender_id }
```